# iframe position: fixed doesn't work when I add some css in iframe

Tags: html, css, iframe

I want to implement `iframe` but it can't work this code below:

```
<html>

<head>
  <style>
    html {
      background: green;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <p>Hello</p>
  <iframe src="xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.html" position="fixed" right="60" bottom="60"
    background="transparent" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0" frameborder="0" style="border:none;"></iframe>
</body>

</html>
```

`iframe` show but it's not working `position='fixed'` and `background='transparent'`.

Comment: iframe tag has no attribute like position so you can not set position with attribute. see here  https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_iframe.asp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use the values in `style` attribute like

```
<html>

<head>
  <style>
    html {
      background: green;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <p>Hello</p>
  <iframe src="xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.html" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0" frameborder="0" style="border:none; position:fixed; right:60px; bottom:60px; background:transparent;"></iframe>
</body>

</html>
```

Hope it works.